# What is the best way to invalidate an entire Amazon CloudFront cache or recreate the entire distribution?

Tags: cache, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

After asking [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/58064/2029), I have decided to recreate some CloudFront distributions, as so many files need to be invalidated.

But instead of creating a new distribution, is it possible to just delete the origin and making an identical one?  Would that work?

Comment: I can see why you might expect it to work, but since you can actually have more than one origin in a distribution, it would be surprising if swapping one out actually invalidated anything.  It's easy enough  try... but I suspect it will not do anything, and you'll need to replace the distribution...

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: Thanks.  I did try, but it's not possible to delete the default origin.